# How to fix in R "Login failed for user: XXX" for connecting to SQL?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, odbc

I tried to create a connection from RStudio to Microsoft SQL 2016, using the following code:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};Server= XXX; Database=XXX;UID=domain\\username;PWD=XXX;TrustServerCertificate=yes")
```

And get this error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 28000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domain\username'.
```

RStudio create values but not a connection to SQL because it doesn't show up in the connection pane.

I am working on a remote desktop, have read rights  and Windows Authentification for SQL Server Management Studio. DBI and ODBC package are installed.

I also tried the code WITHOUT UID and PW but then i got this error:

```
...Cannot open database "XXX" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Then i tried this:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server}, Server=XXX,Database=XXX,Port=1433")
```

And get this Error:

```
...Invalid connection string attribute.
```

Do i need more than read rights or do i need Windows AND/OR SQL Authentification?

Or do you think there is something wrong with the codes I am using?

Comment: You could try creating an odbc-DSN with the Data Sources (ODBC) on Windows and then use that connection to connect. Could also be a way to test that you can connect to the database.

Comment: You need to create a user ''domain\username'' on database that you are trying to access and give appropriate permissions to the same.

Comment: @FilipW: I tried this: con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "database") but i get an erorr that "Data source name too long " - is that possible?!^^

Comment: @Abhishek_Itachi: I will try this later but i will let you know if it is work or not ;)

Comment: Thank you both for answer me so quickly - i am very thankful for every idea i can get :)

Comment: Don't mention it. We can only try to point you in the right direction as this is very hard to reproduce. Don't know why it says that the DSN is to long. Try renaming it and be sure to use the right driver.

Comment: Guys, i finally did it! Thank you so much for your help. I updated the ODBC driver (!) and use the ODBC Data Source Administrator to connect to SQL (like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xQX76nEdvo).Then i was using the following code in R: con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Database name")  and it works! :)